# JAVA output of exe file(executed with ProcessBuilder) does not redirected to console

Tags: java, windows, io, console, windows-console

I'm making java console application for windows which reads user's clipboard and if the content is https://youtube.com link, downloads the audio to mp3 file using [youtube-dl](https://ytdl-org.github.io/youtube-dl/index.html).

I tried to use `ProcessBuilder` to download&convert video to audio, but I keep failing to redirect output of youtube-dl.exe to console.

```
package com.awidesky.YoutubeClipboardAutoDownlader;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;
import java.lang.ProcessBuilder.Redirect;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption;

public class YoutubeAudioDownloader {

    private static final String youtubedlpath = new File("").getAbsolutePath() + "\\resources\\ffmpeg\\bin"; //Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("ffmpeg/bin").getPath();
    private static File downloadPath;
    
    static {
        
        if (!new File(youtubedlpath + "\\youtube-dl.exe").exists()) { throw new Error("youtube-dl.exe does not exist!"); }

    }
    
    static void download(String url, String path) throws Exception {
        
        downloadPath = new File(path);
        
        try {
            
            //Main.log(downloadPath.getAbsolutePath());
            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(youtubedlpath + "\\youtube-dl", "-x", "--audio-format", "mp3", "--audio-quality", "0",  url);
            pb.directory(new File(youtubedlpath));
            Process p = pb.start();
            pb.redirectError(Redirect.INHERIT);
            pb.redirectOutput(Redirect.INHERIT);

            /*
             * Thread stdout = new Thread(() -> {
             * 
             * BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new
             * InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream())); String line = null;
             * 
             * try {
             * 
             * while((line = br.readLine ()) != null) {
             * 
             * Main.log(line);
             * 
             * }
             * 
             * } catch (IOException e) {
             * 
             * // TODO Auto-generated catch block Main.log(e.toString());
             * 
             * }
             * 
             * });
             * 
             * Thread stderr = new Thread(() -> {
             * 
             * BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new
             * InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream())); String line = null;
             * 
             * try {
             * 
             * while((line = br.readLine ()) != null) {
             * 
             * Main.log(line);
             * 
             * }
             * 
             * } catch (IOException e) {
             * 
             * // TODO Auto-generated catch block Main.log(e.toString());
             * 
             * }
             * 
             * });
             * 
             * stdout.start(); stderr.start();
             */
             
            p.waitFor();
            
            
            //Thread.currentThread().sleep(100);
            
            Main.log("founding downloaded file...");
            
            File[] fileList = new File(youtubedlpath).listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
                
                @Override
                public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return name.endsWith("mp3");
                }
                
            });
            
            if(fileList.length ==0 ) { throw new RuntimeException("Didn't dowload any files!"); }
            
            for(File f : fileList) {
                
                Files.copy(f.toPath(), Paths.get(downloadPath.getAbsolutePath() + "\\" + f.getName()) ,StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
                Files.delete(f.toPath());
                
            }
            
            Main.log("Done!");
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

If I get `InputStreamReader` from `Process p` and use two `Thread`s and `while` to print, I can get correct output from eclipse but I can't get any when I launch with `java -jar YoutubeClipBoardAutoDownlaoder.jar`.

And when I use `pb.redirectError(Redirect.INHERIT);` and  `pb.redirectOutput(Redirect.INHERIT);`,
neither eclipse console and Windows console I get output.
Where did I do wrong?

- Whole codes of the project is [here](https://github.com/awidesky/YoutubeClipBoardAutoDownlaoder/blob/master/src/com/awidesky/YoutubeClipboardAutoDownlader/Main.java) and below is the main class of it.

```
package com.awidesky.YoutubeClipboardAutoDownlader;

import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor;
import java.awt.datatransfer.FlavorEvent;
import java.awt.datatransfer.FlavorListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

/** Main class */
public class Main {

    private static ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
    private static boolean isOkToStart = false; /** I don't know why but when you copied something, <code>flavorsChanged</code> invoked twice and we should ignore the first one. */
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        JFileChooser jfc = new JFileChooser();
        jfc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
        jfc.setDialogTitle("Choose directory for saving music!");
        jfc.showDialog(new JFrame(), null);
        File dir = jfc.getSelectedFile();
        
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().addFlavorListener(new FlavorListener() { 
        
                @Override 
                public void flavorsChanged(FlavorEvent e) {

                    if (!isOkToStart) { isOkToStart = true; return; } 

                    System.err.println("CLIPBOARD CHANGED");
                    
                    executorService.submit(() -> {
                        
                        try {
                        
                            Thread.sleep(100);
                            
                            String data = (String)Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().getData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
                    
                            if (data.startsWith("https://www.youtu")) {
                      
                                log("Receved a link from your clipboard : " + data);
                                YoutubeAudioDownloader.download(data, dir.getAbsolutePath());

                            }
                        
                        } catch(Exception err) {
                        
                            log(err.toString());
                        
                        }
               
                    });
                    
                    isOkToStart = !isOkToStart;
                    
                }
        
        });
        
        log("Listning clipboard...");
        
    }
    
    
    public static void log(String data) {
        
        System.out.println(data);
        
    }

}
```

You might ask me...

1. Do you HAVE TO use youtuve-dl?

   -Nope. The only reason I use this is that I didn't find any better one to download audio from youtube.com.
2. Why do you use only one Thread pool?

   -Avoid taking long time in event thread & I think processes got crashed when I execute multiple youtuve-dl.exe(not sure though)

Answer (score 0):

You should redirect output before process start.

```
        pb.redirectError(Redirect.INHERIT);
        pb.redirectOutput(Redirect.INHERIT);
        Process p = pb.start();
```

Comment: Outputs printed correctly in eclipse but not when I started exported jar file... I think youtube-dl.exe did not execute at all.  But it worked perfectly when I ran it from eclipse!

Comment: Maybe should I post another question about exporting eclipse project with Binaries to .jar file...?

Comment: That's weird... Can you see other "System.out.println" texts on your console when run "java -jar xxx.jar"? If you could, then please add console outputs to your question

Comment: I got console output like this: Listening clipboard...  (new line)   CLIPBOARD CHANGED (new line) Receved a link from your clipboard : https://youtube.com/blablabla   Since I can’t get more output(include those from youtube-dl & System.out(like “Done!”)), I suppose youtube-dl.exe did not executed when I run “java -jar xxx.jar”.

Answer (score 0):

I searched several week and finally got it. Problem was not the I/O, but the packaging.
Since I put `.exe`file (the `youtube-dl`file) inside of my `jar`, Java couldn't find the file.
I put resources folder outside of the .jar and it worked well.
But still I can't found out why jvm gave me no ‘’’Error’’’ or ‘’’Exception’’’about that.(maybe problem of the I/O?)